# How can I test combinations of parameters with Matlab Input Parser?

Tags: matlab, validation

I use the [Matlab Inputparser Class](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html) to validate function input, this is a minimal example:

```
function C = multiplyMatrix(A, B)
    p = inputParser;
    addRequired(p, 'A', @isnumeric); % Line A
    addRequired(p, 'B', @isnumeric);
    parse(p, A, B);

    if size(A, 2) ~= size(B, 1) % Line B
        error('Size mismatch.');
    end

    C = A*B;
end
```

How do I integrate tests spanning more than one variable (i.e. the `if`-statement in `Line B`) in the concept of the Matlab Inputparser Class? I only found out how to create tests regarding one variable (see `Line A`).

I am also happy about comments about the usage of this Parser in total.

Comment: Shall I delete this question? I now asked this question here: http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/143295-how-do-i-parse-two-input-arguments-for-matching-dimensions-with-matlab-input-parser